# If my troops fight and die, do I lose them?

Tags: clash-of-clans

If I'm raided and my troops in my clan castle fight and die, do I lose them?
My clan is starting a war today and I'm worried about losing big troops in my clan castle.

Comment: Please clarify do you mean the clan castle in which you send troop request to the clan chat and get toop donations that way or the clan castle in which participants of the war can donate troops to their own team mates

Answer (score 2):

Your war castle and your village castle are completely different. During war, your war castle has to be filled again.

Troops in war castle behave slightly different than your village castle. Even if your troops die in war, they will be replenished. So if anybody attacks your war base again, all of your troops will still be there.

This is not the case for your village castle, if you get raided, troops which die are lost forever. Surviving troops go back to castle. So if you are planning to use high level troops for war attacks, get them just before you attack if you dont have a shield.

Answer (score 1):

From [the wiki](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Clan_Wars_FAQ):

> **What happens to defending Clan Castle troops that are defeated in a
>   war attack?**
>
> After a war attack is over, the defending Clan Castle troops that were
>   defeated are automatically replenished. This means that the same Clan
>   Castle troops will defend a War Base against every war attack.

This is in contrast to normal non-war base defense, which consumes the troops each time.

Comment: I thought that the troops that don't die in a raid will still be in your clan castle

Comment: There is a war clan castle for defense.  its completely different from the clan castle that you use in your village which are for offense.  You are given those troops in the war screen.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you do.  Do not ask for troops until you are ready for your attack unless you have a shield going but if you do you can't get raided so the troops won't die.